# Can we configure multiple (per application) TokenGeneratorImpl classes in api-manager.xml?

Tags: jwt, wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

I am new to WSO2 Api manager.
Recently, I got a requirement for writing CustomJWTTokenGenerator classes for different applications published on a single WSO2 instance.

I followed the below links for reference:
[API Manager 1.9 Documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM190/Passing+Enduser+Attributes+to+the+Backend+Using+JWT)  &
[WSO2 Blog](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2014/12/customize-json-web-token-generation-with-wso2-api-manager-1.8.0/)

The intention is to have different JWTTokenGenerators for different applications published on the same WSO2 server.

I would like to know - Is it possible to configure multiple (per application) TokenGeneratorImpl classes in api-manager.xml for the same wso2 instance?

If not, what could be a possible alternative to achieve this goal?

Comment: What do you mean by different application published? Do you mean API or OAuth Application?

Comment: I mean different API's published in wso2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to set more than one token generation implementations. Only one can be used. You will have to write the logic inside the custom implementation to generate different token based on different application.

Comment: Thanks @Chamila, I have another question - Can we change the encryption mechanism of JWT token from Base64 to any other encryption mechanism in wso2?